# can google signin scopes be "cleared"?

Tags: android, google-signin

I am trying to write an android app to manage GMails.

Is there a way to programatically "clear" a confirmed permission (Scope)?

I have managed to request a Scope using:-

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
  .requestScopes(new Scope("https://mail.google.com/"))
  .requestEmail().build();
```

The first time running the app, I got a permissions confirmation screen and Confirmed. So after that I (correctly) don't get the confirmation screen again.  But I would like to test the permissions screen again. Not even uninstalling the app will provoke it.

I would prefer to just "clear" the Scope in my app. Any ideas?

Comment: I see that permissions can be cleared  here https://myaccount.google.com/permissions but a programatic way would be nice

Comment: Oddly, if I clear the permission using the link to myaccount above, then I still do not get asked to (re)confim it in my app.

Comment: I suppose permissions are cached in the device which is why clearing them may not have an immediate effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `revokeAccess`:

```
private void revokeAccess() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.revokeAccess()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

This will revoke the scope grants recorded server-side and clear the local token cache on the device. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect#disconnect_accounts).